# angularJS, flatten checkboxes list to a CSV

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

I have a service, say [this one](http://www.mocky.io/v2/597866a7130000d704c0fed3) that returns

```
{"001":"Communication","002":"Developement","003":"Environment","004":"Equipment"}
```

I need to put this all in checkboxes, users enable-disable them and finally I recuperate the checked values as CSV keys.

Say user checked the "Development" and "Equipment", so I need to obtain in the "002,004" value.

Here is [my codepen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/dzobMN) with some values already checked (002-Developement and 003-Environment):

```js
angular.module('tagsApp', [])
    .controller('tagsController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        // an initial value is present in the #Tags hidden element
        $scope.tags = $('#Tags').val();
        var tags = $scope.tags.split(",");
        // I need an obj['key']='key' array
        $scope.myTagsArray = {};
        tags.forEach(function (tag) { $scope.myTagsArray[tag] = tag; });

        // get all possible values
        $http.get("http://www.mocky.io/v2/597866a7130000d704c0fed3")
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.allTags = response.data;
            });

        $scope.change = function (myTagsArray) {            
            console.log("myTagsArray: '" + Object.values($scope.myTagsArray).join(",") + "' !");
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tagsApp">
  <label>Tags</label>
  <div ng-controller="tagsController">
    <input type="hidden" id="Tags" value="002,003"/>
    <div ng-cloak ng-repeat="(key, value) in allTags">
      <label for="tag_{{key}}">
        <input type="checkbox" 
               id="tag_{{key}}"
               ng-model="tagsArray['{{key}}']"
               ng-true-value="'{{key}}'"
               ng-false-value=""
               ng-change="change(tagsArray)" />
        {{value}}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However all that code does not really work. Where is the problem?

Comment: Your ng-model does not need {{}} . Change it like this ng-model="tagsArray[key']"
               ng-true-value="'key'"

Comment: thank you, good point, unfortunately this does not solve the problem...

Comment: Where are the checkboxes in your codepen?

Comment: I don't know, probably there is a problem with the API (CORS)? the checkboxes does not appear in the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code if you want the corresponding keys to be saved on checking

```js
angular.module("tagsApp", []).controller("tagsController", [
  "$scope",
  "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    // get all possible values
    $scope.allTags = {
      "001": "Communication",
      "002": "Developement",
      "003": "Environment",
      "004": "Equipment"
    };
    $scope.hidval="002,003";
    $scope.checked = [];
    $scope.tags = [];
    $scope.keys = [];
    $scope.tags = $scope.hidval.split(",");
    $scope.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
      $scope.checked[tag] = true;
      $scope.keys.push(tag);
    });

    $scope.change = function(mykey) {
      var ind = $scope.keys.indexOf(mykey);
      if ($scope.checked[mykey]) {
        $scope.checked[mykey] = false;
        $scope.keys.splice(ind, 1);
      } else {
        $scope.checked[mykey] = true;
        $scope.keys.push(mykey);
      }
        var result=$scope.keys.join();
        console.log(result);           
        $scope.hidval=result;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tagsApp">
  <label>Tags</label>
  <div ng-controller="tagsController">
    <input type="hidden" id="Tags" ng-model="hidval"/>{{hidval}}
    <div ng-cloak ng-repeat="(key, value) in allTags">
      <label for="tag_{{key}}">
        <input type="checkbox" 
               id="tag_{{key}}"
               ng-checked="checked[key]"
               ng-click="change(key)"/>
        {{value}}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to bind the hidden input value in order to obtain a CSV and take into consideration the initial values?

Comment: How are trying to convert the values into a CSV? What initial values?

Comment: Yes . You don't have to put it in {{}}

Comment: it put me "key" instead of "001"... I have a "working" example here, where the initial values are loaded, but is not really working, cause the cases don't changes... ( https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/XabJqO

Comment: @Serge Idk what you are trying to do but I have updated my answer. Check if this is what u require

Comment: yeah, now the problem is that hidval initialization... I have the value on the server side, so as ng-init not recommended...

Comment: So now you can call the service and update the value of hidval based on the response. You can try my method and check if it is working properly.

Comment: unfortunately the service gives the full values collection, not the actual value of an individual field... that value I have in the server-side view...`<input type=hidden asp-for="@Model.Tags">`

Comment: But you can map each field to each instance of the actual value

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Vivz answer (thanks a lot for the effort), here is the working solution

```js
angular.module("tagsApp", []).controller("tagsController", [
  "$scope",
  function($scope) {
    // get all possible values
    $scope.allTags = {
      "001": "Communication",
      "002": "Developement",
      "003": "Environment",
      "004": "Equipment"
    };
    
    $scope.selectedTags = $("#Tags").val().split(",");   
    $scope.tagsArray = {};
    // init all with "false"
    Object.keys($scope.allTags).forEach(function(tag) { $scope.tagsArray[tag] = ""; });
    // check pre-selected from hidden #Tags
    $scope.selectedTags.forEach(function(tag) { $scope.tagsArray[tag] = tag; });
    
    $scope.change = function(mykey) {
      var result = Object.values($scope.tagsArray)
                         .filter(function(o){return o;})
                         .join(); // remove the empty values in array          
      $("#Tags").val(result); // update the hidden #Tags

      console.log(result);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tagsApp">
  <label>Tags</label>
  <div ng-controller="tagsController">
    <input type="hidden" id="Tags" value="002,003"/>
    <div ng-cloak ng-repeat="(key, value) in allTags">
      <label for="tag_{{key}}">
        <input type="checkbox" 
               id="tag_{{key}}"
               ng-model="tagsArray[key]"
               ng-true-value="{{key}}"
               ng-false-value=""
               ng-change="change(key)" />
        {{value}}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still don't understand why my answer is not correct. What is it that you wanted?

Comment: Your answer is ok, but is not complete. I needed the value of Tags to be updated with a CSV string, obtained from your array

Comment: Where are u setting the value for CSV strings in your code?

Comment: in my solution I update it in the hidden field. And is a little bit difference cause `change` practically is not used (just to update that CSV value)

Comment: Oh I see . You are doing that here  $("#Tags").val(result); . I didn't know that u wanted it to be like this. :)

Comment: your solution also working good, maybe is more optimal, I don't know :)

Comment: I have updated my code with CSV mapping and removed all jquery. This solution will be more optimal. :)